# Heroku cant login longboard. connection is not private

Tags: git, heroku, authentication, heroku-toolbelt

I am unable to clone the project to my PC.

I get this error :

[image: command line heroku clone error]

Also, Its weird how I cant access any heroku links. I am redirected to this link : `https://longboard.heroku.com/login?state=https%3A%2F%2Fdashboard.heroku.com%2Fauth%2Fheroku%2Fcallback%3F!`

I dont know what is longboard and how am I getting there.

`And heroku works fine in other network connection.` I dont know if security is compromised or something on this network. I googled to figure it out And I endup with suggestions to setup pc date time correct or reinstalling chrome browser etc. But I dont know really whats the issue.

Its not to do with SSL expiration as far as i know.

[image: this is what I get when accessed through browser]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It was problem with network connection. make sure you dont have VPN or so not switched on, as it changes your identity and heroku prevents login